# Regarding proof of converse to Girsanovs theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, radon-nikodym

This is regarding an argument from Arbitrage Theory by Thomas Björk - Theorem 11.6, but is attempted self contained.

Consider a Wiener process W on probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\{\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\in[0,T]},P)$. Assume that the filtration is generated by W, and that $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{F}_T$.

Assume Q is a probability measure absolutely continuous with respect to P on  $\mathcal{F}_T$. Denote $L_T$ the Radon-Nikodym derivative and define $L_t = E[L_T \lvert \mathcal{F}_t]$ a martingale.

By the martingale representation theorem we can find $g_t$ such that 
$$
dL_t = g_t dW_t
$$
If we define $\phi_t = \frac{1}{L_t} g_t$ this should suffice as a Girsanov transformation, showing that in the filtration of the Wiener process any absolutely continuous transformation is of a Girsanov type.

The text says: "There remains a small problem namely when $L_t=0$ but also this can be handled". How does one handle that problem?

Comment: The set of $\omega\in\Omega$ where $L_t=0$ is a set that must have $Q$-measure zero. What $W_t'$ is doing there doesn't matter.

Comment: So you  simply define $\phi_t = 0$ on $\{\omega \in \Omega : L_t(\omega)=0\}$?

Comment: I guess that works. The $Q$-measure doesn't see what you do in there.